# How to make pop up like this

Tags: flutter, frontend, icons

Do you guys know how to make pop up that small and appear below icon like this? I have made it with AlertDialog, but the pop up is on the center of the screen and too big.

[image]

Comment: That is Popupmenubutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PopupMenuButton from Flutter sdk

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html

You can profile ShapeBorder as RoundedRectangleBorder.

Answer (score 2):

Using this code you can show the menu where you need

**Function**

```
  void showPopUpMenuAtTap(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        details.globalPosition.dx,
        details.globalPosition.dy,
        details.globalPosition.dx,
        details.globalPosition.dy,
      ),
      items: const [
        PopupMenuItem<String>(value: '1', child: Text('menu option 1')),
        PopupMenuItem<String>(value: '2', child: Text('menu option 2')),
        PopupMenuItem<String>(value: '3', child: Text('menu option 3')),
      ],
    ).then((value) {
      if (value == null) return;

      if (value == "1") {
        //code here
        log("message", name: value);
      } else if (value == "2") {
        //code here
        log("message", name: value);
      } else if (value == "3") {
        //code here
        log("message", name: value);
      }
    });
  }
```

**You can call like this**

```
GestureDetector(
          child: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onTapDown: (details) => showPopUpMenuAtTap(context, details),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `popupmenu` not `AlertDialog` here the [documantain](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) of `popupmenu`

with the feature shape, you could play with the shape and size ...etc